# Verificar una CURP con RegEx

Tags: regex

Verificar una CURP que cumpla con lo siguiente:

Los primeros cuatro caracteres deben ser solo letras
Los siguientes 6 caracteres deben ser dígitos
El siguiente carácter puede ser H o M
Los siguientes 2 caracteres corresponde al estado de nacimiento
Los siguientes 3 caracteres pueden ser una letra consonante
Los últimos 2 caracteres pueden ser letras o números

Comment: Por favor lee el artículo sobre [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), recuerda que tu problema debe ser reproducible y debes de mostrar lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Una buena pregunta tiene mejores posibilidades de ser respondida, además de que evitar ser cerrada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La validación de regex la puedes hacer con la siguiente expresión.

```
[\A-Z]{4}[0-9]{6}[HM]{1}[A-Z]{2}[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]{3}([A-Z]{2})?([0-9]{2})?
```

Donde:

- [A-Z] acepta todas las letras en mayúsculas, {4} espera 4 caracteres
- [0-9] acepta todos los números, {2} espera 2 caracteres
- [HM] acepta únicamente H o M, {1} espera 1 carácter.
- [BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ] acepta todas las consonantes.
- ([A-Z]{2})? acepta cualquier conjunto de 2 letras mayúsculas de forma opcional
- ([0-9]{2})? acepta cualquier conjunto de 2 números de forma opcional

Puedes validar tus expresiones regulares [aqui](https://regexr.com/)